# TensorFlow 2 Panda Tutorial Preprocessing Confusion

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm following one of the TensorFlow's [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv) and I don't understand the purpose of the following code:

```
numeric_inputs = {name:input for name,input in inputs.items()
                  if input.dtype==tf.float32}

x = layers.Concatenate()(list(numeric_inputs.values()))
norm = layers.Normalization()
norm.adapt(np.array(titanic[numeric_inputs.keys()]))
all_numeric_inputs = norm(x)

all_numeric_inputs
```

This is my current attempt:

1. `numeric_inputs` is a map of filtered results
2. I don't understand why use `layers.Concatenate()` here. I have read the docs.
3. I understand that `norm.adapt()` need to be called before using `norm` as a (starting) layer of the `Sequential` model (from the [section above](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv#basic_preprocessing)). But why call it with `x` here, i.e. `norm(x)`?

Btw, any advice regarding learning with official tutorials? I found that some of them are still too vague for me.

Answer (score 1):

The part of code you provide is in the *Mixed data types* section of [the tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv#mixed_data_types).
To answer your question, here is some of the code from the tutorial:

```
numeric_inputs = {name:input for name,input in inputs.items()
                  if input.dtype==tf.float32}

x = layers.Concatenate()(list(numeric_inputs.values()))
norm = layers.Normalization()
norm.adapt(np.array(titanic[numeric_inputs.keys()]))
all_numeric_inputs = norm(x)

all_numeric_inputs
```

where `titanic` is a pandas dataframe:

```
titanic = pd.read_csv("https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/train.csv")
titanic_features = titanic.copy()

inputs = {}

for name, column in titanic_features.items():
  dtype = column.dtype
  if dtype == object:
    dtype = tf.string
  else:
    dtype = tf.float32

  inputs[name] = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name=name, dtype=dtype)
```

Back to your questions:

1. `numeric_inputs` is a filtered dictionary in which only the numeric  symbolic tensors (of type float32) are kept,
2. the `Concatenate` layer allows to obtain a single tensor from the filtered dictionary (which is first converted into a list),
3. As the [functional API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional) will be used to define the Model, the data is normalized with the `Normalization` layer (instantiated as `norm` here) which is adapted/trained on some data. The normalization layer takes as input the output of the previous layer `x`.